# Django Cannot keep last 3 row of database

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to keep latest 3 row of each key and delete oldest row if data of each key more than 3 row. I have sample data like this.

```
id  value key  created
1    a1   001  2023-04-23 01:01:00  <= delete oldest of key 001
2    a2   001  2023-04-23 01:02:00
3    a3   001  2023-04-23 01:03:00
4    a4   001  2023-04-23 01:04:00
5    a5   002  2023-04-23 01:05:00  <= delete oldest of key 002
6    a6   002  2023-04-23 01:06:00
7    a5   002  2023-04-23 01:07:00
8    a6   002  2023-04-23 01:08:00
```

I get latest 3 row order by create and delete oldest with this code.

```
if Key.objects.filter(key=key).exists():

    objects_to_keep = Data.objects.filter(key=key).order_by('-created').values_list("id", flat=True)[:3]
    objects_to_keep = list(objects_to_keep)
    Data.objects.exclude(pk__in=objects_to_keep).delete()
```

If I add new row key=001 it remove all data of key 002 and the same when add new row key=002 it remove all data key 001. The output should be like this.

```
id  value key  created
2    a2   001  2023-04-23 01:02:00
3    a3   001  2023-04-23 01:03:00
4    a4   001  2023-04-23 01:04:00
6    a6   002  2023-04-23 01:06:00
7    a5   002  2023-04-23 01:07:00
8    a6   002  2023-04-23 01:08:00
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new row with key=001, this code excludes some rows with key=001 and deletes other rows, which includes all the rows with key=002

try this:

```
if Key.objects.filter(key=key).exists():
    objects_to_delete = Data.objects.filter(key=key).order_by('-created').values_list("id", flat=True)[3:]
    objects_to_delete = list(objects_to_delete)
    Data.objects.filter(pk__in=objects_to_delete).delete()
```